# KeyListener not detecting keypress

Tags: java, keyboard, keylistener, keyevent

I have a game built and I want to be able to pause the game when the **P Key** is pressed. However, whilst the game is running the `KeyListener` does not seem to be detecting the **P Key** has been pressed.

Is my code correct? Have I placed `addKeyListener` in the right place?

There are similar questions on SO however they all seem to be using `JFrame` whereas I am using the [ACM Graphics Library](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/). Not sure if that makes a difference.

Main game loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());

    displayStartScreen();
    displayUI();
    drawBricks(getWidth() / 2.0, BRICK_Y_OFFSET);
    drawPaddle();

    while (lives > 0) {

        drawBall();
        playGame(); // additional game loop

        if (brickCounter == 0) {
            removeAll(); // removes all game objects
            displayUI();
            drawBricks(getWidth() / 2.0, BRICK_Y_OFFSET);
            drawPaddle();
            brickCounter = 100;
            }
        }
    } 
    if (brickCounter > 0) {
        removeAll();
        printGameOver();
    }
}
```

Additional game loop:

```
private void playGame() {

    getBallVelocity();

    while (true) {

        moveBall();
        updateUI();

        if (ball.getY() >= getHeight()) {
            lives--;
            break;
        }
        if (brickCounter == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

KeyListener class:

```
private class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
            System.out.println("Key 'P' has been pressed!"); // test
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { /* Empty body */ }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks okay.  Is acm.grachics (whatever that is) receiving the keypresses?  Does it need focus?  Have you tried using a JFrame to check your code?

Comment: Is addKeyListener a method provided by your library? Do you assign the listener to the correct component?

Comment: @ItFreak it was, however I had spelled it incorrectly and the IDE had not picked this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem. The code

```
addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
```

is incorrect, it should be

```
addKeyListeners(new MyKeyListener());
```